# Passing variable number of arguments to a function

Tags: php, reflection

I have two classes:

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $B = new B;
        $ArgumentReflection = new ReflectionMethod($B, "b");
        $ArgumentArray = array();
        foreach($ArgumentReflection->getParameters() as $ArgumentName) {
            if(isset($Request[$ArgumentName->name])) {
             $ArgumentArray[$ArgumentName->name] =  $_REQUEST[$ArgumentName->name];
            }
        }
    }
}

class B {
    function b($one, $two, $three) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is a simplified example. The idea is that I might want to define multiple functions in multiple methods and call them with different number of arguments. I need to find a solution of how to call the method and pass it, for example, needed `$_REQUEST` variables. For example, if I have three functions in class B like this:

```
class B {
    function a($seven, $six) {

    }
    function b($one, $two, $three) {

    }
    function c($zebra, $cat, $monkey) {

    }
}
```

If I pass `"a"` to the ReflectionMethod,  I want function `a` to be called like this: `$B->a($_REQUEST["seven"], $_REQUEST["six"])`.
If I pass `"b"`, then like this: `$B->b($_REQUEST["one"], $_REQUEST["two"], $_REQUEST["three"]);` and so on.

Obciously, the `...` token available in php 5.6 is not the solution,

Any hint? Thanx

Comment: You already have a `ReflectionMethod` instance, so just call [`->invokeArgs()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php) on it.

Comment: @Jack yes I have obviously overlooked this method while reading the manual...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, since not much is documented on Reflections in PHP, I'm posting my own answer, all thanx to [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/ja%CD%A2ck) for pointing me in the right direction.

[ReflectionMethod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) inherits [invokeArgs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invokeargs.php) function, through which you pass an array of arguments. So, in the end to do what I had in mind, I just added one line after the posted code and now it looks like this:

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $B = new B;
        $ArgumentReflection = new ReflectionMethod($B, "b");
        $ArgumentArray = array();
        foreach($ArgumentReflection->getParameters() as $ArgumentName) {
            if(isset($Request[$ArgumentName->name])) {
                $ArgumentArray[$ArgumentName->name] =  $_REQUEST[$ArgumentName->name];
            }
        }

        $ArgumentReflection->invokeArgs($B, $ArgumentArray);

    }
}

class B {
    function b($one, $two, $three) {
        ...
    }
}
```

All done. Good luck everyone.